# Running a puppet in MacOS

Tags: macos, puppet

I new in puppet, i'm trying to run a simple puppet like this:

```
node 'mymac.local' {
         package { 'nginx':
           ensure => installed,
         }
}
```

But it shows this error:

```
Error: Mac OS X PKG DMG's must specify a package source.
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[mymac.local]/Package[nginx]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Mac OS X PKG DMG's must specify a package source.
```

I can't find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a provider (probably brew):

```
package { "nginx":
  ensure    => latest,
  provider  => 'brew'
}
```

I'd suggest looking at the [boxen project's](https://github.com/boxen) [nginx module](https://github.com/boxen/puppet-nginx). [Gary Larizza has a great post on setting up boxen on OSX](http://garylarizza.com/blog/2013/02/15/puppet-plus-github-equals-laptop-love/)